# how to copy a file between 2 computers on the network in python

Tags: python

I am trying to move a log file from a computer, where an operation is performed, to another computer, that will get the log file and process it, returning a document with the result of the analysis.

I am using Python for the job, but I am open to other options (I have to run this copy via console on OSX, due the fact that most of my work is done in shell scripting; so cannot use any  visual solution; anything that can be launched via a script would work too); any suggestion is more than welcome since I do not really have a favorite way to do this (just trying the less problematic....I do not need any security encryption since both of the computers are on my internal network, no communication with the outside is performed).

Hope that someone can point me to the right solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy

Comment: I know about SCP, but it requires an SSH connection, and I want to just copy the file without authentication.

Comment: I would just do a `ssh-copy-id` first to sidestep the authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS mount the filesystem, then both systems can access the same files as if they were local.  Otherwise you could use sockets.

Comment: Good point; mounting the shared dir on one machine allows me to use the standard cp; thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

I use this all the time at home so I don't have to keep file sharing daemons running constantly:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

On the client machine, use a browser or wget.

In fact I use it so often I made this script that prints the IP Address also, named `serv`.  Feel free to hack it into your needs. Just cd to a folder and `serv` it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess as sub
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer as httpd

# override this method to speed up connection
def _bare_address_string(self):
    host, port = self.client_address[:2]
    return '%s' % host
BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.address_string = _bare_address_string

# get ip address and print
info = sub.Popen('/sbin/ifconfig', stdout=sub.PIPE).communicate()[0]
tokens = []
for line in info.split('\n'):
    if 'inet' in line:
        if '127.0.0.1' not in line:
            tokens = line.split()
print
print '    ', tokens[1].replace(':', ': '), '\n    ',


# start server
try:
    httpd.test()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '\x08\x08Killed'
```

Comment: Interesting solution; I will give it a try, even if it seems a bit more complex than what I had in mind :)

Comment: The first line is about as simple as it gets.